# kubectl port-forward forwards to incorrect port (hashcorp/consul)

Tags: kubernetes, consul, kind, servicemesh

Following Hashicorp's [Deploy Consul on Kubernetes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/tutorials/get-started-kubernetes/kubernetes-gs-deploy) on Ubuntu 22.04 Server/amd64.

1. Cloned the repo. Done.
2. Created the Kubernetes cluster using Kind. Done.
3. Deployed the datacenter using consul-k8s. Done.
4. Set environment variables. Done.
5. View consul service. Bonk.

The result of this step seemed suspicious...

```
$ kubectl port-forward svc/consul-ui --namespace consul 8501:443
> Forwarding from [::1]:8501 -> 8501
```

Obviously the port forward from 8501 to 8501 is not expected.

Consul catalog isn't working:

```
$ consul catalog services
> Error listing services: Get "https://127.0.0.1:8501/v1/catalog/services": EOF
```

Why is kubectl forwarding from 8501 to 8501 when it should be forwarding from 8501 to 443?

I haven't changed any configurations from the tutorial.

consul-k8s logs:

```
==> Installing Consul
 ✓ Downloaded charts.
 --> creating 1 resource(s)
 --> Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" ServiceAccount
 --> serviceaccounts "consul-tls-init" not found
 --> creating 1 resource(s)
 --> Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" Role
 --> roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "consul-tls-init" not found
 --> creating 1 resource(s)
 --> Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" RoleBinding
 --> rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "consul-tls-init" not found
 --> creating 1 resource(s)
 --> Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" Job
 --> jobs.batch "consul-tls-init" not found
 --> creating 1 resource(s)
 --> Watching for changes to Job consul-tls-init with timeout of 10m0s
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: ADDED
 --> consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
 --> consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
 --> consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
 --> consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
 --> consul-tls-init: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-tls-init: MODIFIED
 --> Starting delete for "consul-tls-init" Job
 --> creating 45 resource(s)
 --> beginning wait for 45 resources with timeout of 10m0s
 --> StatefulSet is ready: consul/consul-server. 1 out of 1 expected pods are ready
 --> creating 1 resource(s)
 --> Watching for changes to Job consul-server-acl-init-cleanup with timeout of 10m0s
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: ADDED
 --> consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: MODIFIED
 --> consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: MODIFIED
 --> consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: MODIFIED
 --> consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: MODIFIED
 --> consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
 --> Add/Modify event for consul-server-acl-init-cleanup: MODIFIED
 --> Starting delete for "consul-server-acl-init-cleanup" Job
 ✓ Consul installed in namespace "consul".
```

Not sure whether consul-tls-init is causing the issue... but not much in terms of google search results.

Using "helm install" method also fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does the port-forwarding work, apart of the misleading message? If yes, it is kind of a bug in kubectl but it won't be fixed most likely. It's caused by the service, consul-ui in your case, exposing the port 443 which is mapped by name to the port 8081 of the pod. The message shows erronously the port number of the  pod. See full explenation here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1036